# Inserting values from parent table into child table using triggers

Tags: postgresql

I have a parent table linked to child tables and each row has a unique well number (primary key). All the tables have elevation values which also must be the same, since each row in the different tables corresponds to the same well. Therefore, what I want is that when the parent table gets an insert (or update) these values get cascaded down to the children.

So I created a trigger function on the parent table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_elev_insert()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
    declare
    well_no_var varchar (50);
    elev_var numeric(6,2);
    begin
        select well_no from well_parent into well_no_var;
        select elev from well_parent into elev_var;
        insert into well_construct (well_no, elev)
        values (well_no_var, elev_var);
        
    end;
$BODY$;
```

And the trigger that calls the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_elev_insert
    AFTER INSERT
    ON public.well_parent
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION public.fn_elev_insert();
```

But I get this error when trying to insert into parent table:

ERROR:  Key (well_no)=(bh002) already exists.duplicate key value violates unique constraint "well_construct_pkey"

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "well_construct_pkey"
SQL state: 23505
Detail: Key (well_no)=(bh002) already exists.
Context: SQL statement "insert into well_construct (well_no, elev)
values (well_no_var, elev_var)"
PL/pgSQL function fn_elev_insert() line 8 at SQL statement
SQL statement "insert into well_construct (well_no, elev)
values (well_no_var, elev_var)"
PL/pgSQL function fn_elev_insert() line 8 at SQL statement:

If I view the rows with SELECT, both tables are empty so there is no apparent duplicate key violation. Something to do with the order of operations? (using BEFORE event will just give a row of nulls). Do I need to use a WHEN clause in the trigger definition?
Using a subquery -> "insert into" child x,x... values(select x, x from parent) that doesn't work either.

Comment: Please see [mre]. Without the table DDL, others have to guess about the model structure based on the narrative. It appears that your model is not suitably normalized. Attributes of a well should not be replicated to the child tables. If the elevation of the well is needed when querying the child table, then the query should join to the parent table to get the needed value.

Comment: Perhaps you insert two `well_parent` rows with the same `well_no`?

Comment: 1) This `select well_no from well_parent into well_no_var;` and the same for `select elev...` is not necessary. Just do `insert into well_construct (well_no, elev) values (NEW.well_no_var, NEW.elev_var);`  FYI, per comment from @JohnH, you don't need to insert the `elev` value.2) `BEFORE` will work properly if you use `RETURN NEW`' 3) Spend some time here [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Comment: @John - Elevation is needed for the other tables because they use generated columns to adjust well depth, water level, etc to their respective elevations.  I could use a trigger approach to this, but many columns in several tables (multiple screen levels, multiple geological contacts) need this adjustment.

Comment: From your original post and prior comment, it seems like you've needlessly complicated both the data structure and calculations. Unless your tables are huge, a better approach might be to create a normalized schema and use views to capture the calculations. Without schema details, it's very difficult for the SO community to offer useful suggestions.